# R solver optimization

Tags: r, optimization, solver

I am new to R solver and I want to have a simple example in R for the below problem:

I have four columns which I calculate the individual sums as the illustrated sample example below:

[image]

**The problem I want to solve in R:**

Find the optimal lines that satisfies, **simultaneously**, the below statements:

1. For the first two columns (a, b) the individual summations to be more close to 0
2. The sums of (c, d) to be more close to 5

I do not have restrictions of which package solver to use. It could be helpful to have an example of R code for this!

**EDIT**

For the same solution I would like  to apply some rules:

1. I want the sum(c) > sum(d) AND sum(d) < (static number, like 5)
2. Also, if I want the sums to fall into a range of numbers and not just static numbers, how the solution could it be written?

Comment: I've found `NlcOptim` nice to use. Very flexible once you get the hang of it and is quick. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NlcOptim/NlcOptim.pdf

Comment: Please do not use images to show your data. It means that anyone who answers has to retype all the data to run their code.  Use text instead.  I have done it this time for you in my answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you @JonnyPhelps

Answer (score 2):

Using `M` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end we find the `b` which minimizes the following objective where `b` is a 0/1 vector:

```
sum((b %*% M - c(0, 0, 5, 5))^2)
```

**1) CVXR**  Using the CVXR package we get a solution c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1) which means choose rows 1, 4 and 5.

```
library(CVXR)

n <- nrow(M)
b <- Variable(n, boolean = TRUE)

pred <- t(b) %*% M
y <- c(0, 0, 5, 5)

objective <- Minimize(sum((t(y) - pred)^2))
problem <- Problem(objective)
soln <- solve(problem)

bval <- soln$getValue(b)
zapsmall(c(bval))
## [1] 1 0 0 1 1
```

**2) Brute Force** Alternately since there are only 5 rows there are only 2^5 possible solutions so we can try them all and pick the one which minimizes the objective.  First we compute a matrix `solns` with 2^5 columns such that each column is one possible solution.  Then we compute the objective function for each column and take the one which minimizes it.

```
n <- nrow(M)

inverse.which <- function(ix, n) replace(integer(n), ix, 1)
L <- lapply(0:n, function(i) apply(combn(n, i), 2, inverse.which, n))
solns <- do.call(cbind, L)
pred <- t(t(solns) %*% M)
obj <- colSums((pred - c(0, 0, 5, 5))^2)
solns[, which.min(obj)]
## [1] 1 0 0 1 1
```

### Note

```
M <- matrix(c(.38, -.25, .78, .83, -.65,
.24, -.35, .44, -.88, .15,
3, 5, 13, -15, 18,
18, -7, 23, -19, 7), 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! 
Two additional questions. If I want to have some rules for the same results, for example the sum of column c to be bigger than sum of column d, how could it be written?

Second: If for the sum i do not want to have a static number like 3, 5 etc but a wide range like (5 - 8), how could it be written?

Comment: CVXR will continue to work provided your revised objective and added constraints maintain the convexity of the problem.  See the CVXR documentation.  For the brute force method you can modify the objective as desired and you can simply remove any column in `pred` and the corresponding column in `solns` that violates the constraint.